# How do I find change point in a timeseries in PoweBi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a group of people who started receiving a specific type of social benefit called benefitA, I am interested in knowing what(if any) social benefits the people in the group might have received immediately before they started receiving BenefitA.

My optimal result would be a table with the number people who was receiving respectively BenefitB, BenefitC and not receiving any benefit “BenefitNon” immediately before they started receiving BenefitA.

My data is organized as a relation database with a Facttabel containing an ID for each person in my data and several dimension tables connected to the facttabel. The important ones here at DimDreamYdelse(showing type of benefit received), DimDreamTid(showing week and year). Here is an example of the raw data.

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAiWo.png)

I'm not sure how to approach this in PowerBi as I am fairly new to this program. Any advice is most welcome.

I have tried to solve the problem in SQL but as I need this as part of a running report i need to do it in PowerBi. This bit of code might however give some context to what I want to do.

USE FLISDATA_Beskaeftigelse;
SELECT       dbo.FactDream.DimDreamTid , dbo.FactDream.DimDreamBenefit , dbo.DimDreamTid.Aar, dbo.DimDreamTid.UgeIAar, dbo.DimDreamBenefit.Benefit, 
FROM            dbo.FactDream INNER JOIN
                         dbo.DimDreamTid ON dbo.FactDream.DimDreamTid = dbo.DimDreamTid.DimDreamTidID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.DimDreamYdelse ON dbo.FactDream.DimDreamBenefit = dbo.DimDreamYdelse.DimDreamBenefitID
WHERE        (dbo.DimDreamYdelse.Ydelse LIKE 'Benefit%') AND (dbo.DimDreamTid.Aar = '2019')
ORDER BY dbo.DimDreamTid.Aar, dbo.DimDreamTid.UgeIAar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use PowerQuery to transform your table into more suitable form for your analysis. Things would be much easier if each row of the table represents the "change" of benefit plan like this.

```
| Person ID | Benefit From | Benefit To |    Date    |
|-----------|--------------|------------|------------|
|        15 | BenefitNon   | BenefitA   | 2019-07-01 |
|        15 | BenefitA     | BenefitNon | 2019-12-01 |
|        17 | BenefitC     | BenefitA   | 2019-06-01 |
|        17 | BenefitA     | BenefitB   | 2019-08-01 |
|        17 | BenefitB     | BenefitA   | 2019-09-01 |
| ...
```

Then you can simply count the numbers by `COUNTROWS(BenefitChanges)` filtering/slicing with both `Benefit From` and `Benefit To`.